# Hbase shell command that shows table configurations.

Tags: hbase, hbase-shell

I created a table in HBase

`create 'test', 'x', 'y', 'z', {NUMREGIONS => 10, SPLITALGO => 'UniformSplit'}`

When I issue `describe 'test'`

`hbase(main):016:0> describe 'test'
Table test is ENABLED
test
COLUMN FAMILIES DESCRIPTION
{NAME => 'x', BLOOMFILTER => 'ROW', VERSIONS => '1', IN_MEMORY => 'false', KEEP_DELETED_CELLS => 'FALSE', DATA_BLOCK_ENCODING => 'NONE', TTL => 'FOREVER', COMPRESSION => 'NONE', MIN_VERSIONS => '0', BLOCK
CACHE => 'true', BLOCKSIZE => '65536', REPLICATION_SCOPE => '0'}
{NAME => 'y', BLOOMFILTER => 'ROW', VERSIONS => '1', IN_MEMORY => 'false', KEEP_DELETED_CELLS => 'FALSE', DATA_BLOCK_ENCODING => 'NONE', TTL => 'FOREVER', COMPRESSION => 'NONE', MIN_VERSIONS => '0', BLOCK
CACHE => 'true', BLOCKSIZE => '65536', REPLICATION_SCOPE => '0'}
{NAME => 'z', BLOOMFILTER => 'ROW', VERSIONS => '1', IN_MEMORY => 'false', KEEP_DELETED_CELLS => 'FALSE', DATA_BLOCK_ENCODING => 'NONE', TTL => 'FOREVER', COMPRESSION => 'NONE', MIN_VERSIONS => '0', BLOCK
CACHE => 'true', BLOCKSIZE => '65536', REPLICATION_SCOPE => '0'}
3 row(s) in 0.0170 seconds`

`describe` command does not show the `SPLITALGO` and `NUMREGIONS`.

Is there a HBase shell command which shows the table configurations?

Answer (score 0):

I guess there is no straightforward way, but you can get number of regions via

```
(get_splits "YourTableName").count
```